# Time Zone for Spring Mock MVC tests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How can the time zone for SpringMock MVC tests be set?
Our Spring Boot applications are all running with

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

set at Application startup. But I found no way to set this for the MockMvcRequestBuilders. Setting it manually (in test or BeforeClass) didn't change anything = still machine time-zone is used...

Comment: Are you setting the timezone outside of a spring bean on startup?(like before startup in the main method) is that the reason why you need to handle it separately for tests compared to the running application?

Comment: Yeah. Had it wrong. Thought I could just copy the Application class for testing purpose. But here the main class is never called. At least if using MockMVC. Moving the TimeZone setting to the

@Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {...}

there. And now it is called...

Comment: related: [How do I force a Spring Boot JVM into UTC time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54316667/1371329)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it using a @Configuration class. If you annotate your tests with @SpringBootTest, as Spring loads the context before execute testes, you'll have your default timezone configurated correctly.

I'd just inserted this class below in one of my projects and all my @SpringBootTest annotated tests started to respect UTC timezone. You can replace to use the timezone you want to.

```
@Configuration
public class TimeZoneConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimeZoneConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public TimeZone timeZone(){
        TimeZone defaultTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        TimeZone.setDefault(defaultTimeZone);
        LOGGER.info("Spring boot application running in UTC timezone :"+new Date());
        return defaultTimeZone;
    }

}
```