# How do I force a Spring Boot JVM into UTC time zone?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, timezone

I saw [Force Java timezone as GMT/UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627992/force-java-timezone-as-gmt-utc)

I tried

- mvn spring-boot:run -Dexec.args="-Duser.timezone=GMT"
- mvn spring-boot:run -Dexec.args="-Duser.timezone=UTC"
- `user.timezone=UTC` in `config/application.properties`
- `user.timezone=GMT`
- In the pom.xml:

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <properties>
                <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=UTC</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
              </properties>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```
- mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Duser.timezone=UTC"

But it prints out

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]

Spring Boot 1.5.19, Java 8

Comment: This works for Spring Boot v1: `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Duser.timezone=UTC"`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [`spring-boot.run.jvmArguments` property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#jvmArguments) if you want to pass JVM options from Maven Spring Boot Plugin to forked Spring Boot application:

```
<properties>
  <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=UTC</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
</properties>
```

This is be equivalent to command line syntax:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Duser.timezone=UTC"
```

or when running a fully packaged Spring Boot application:

```
java -Duser.timezone=UTC -jar app.jar
```

Comment: The first option `<properties` did not work. It still prints `id="America/New_York"`.  The second option `-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments...` also didn't work.

Comment: @Chloe work for me with `-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Duser.timezone=UTC"` or `-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Duser.timezone=America/New_York` with Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE and Java 11. Project generated with https://start.spring.io/.

Comment: I see. Must be a bug in v1 and fixed in v2. `java -Duser.timezone=UTC -jar target\App-SNAPSHOT.war` *does* work.

Comment: <properties>
  <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=UTC</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
</properties>
that did not work but if you use jvmArguments instead that worked for me. reference:
the https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#jvmArguments

as simple as:

<jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=UTC</jvmArguments>

Comment: Please note that jvmArguments are only applied if you also set the property `fork` to true. 
However, I was able to get it working with `mvn spring-boot:run -Duser.timezone=UTC`

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, is there an option to put this in application.properties file?

Answer (score 67):

I think you can set your application's timezone on your application level. I think this link will help you.
https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/spring-boot/how-to-set-spring-boot-settimezone.html

So What you need to do is adding "@PostConstruct" annotation to the main class where "@SpringBootApplication" annotation is located, and add timezone setting method there. Here is an example.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HellotimezoneApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HellotimezoneApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
      // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
      TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

}
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: This is not going to work for code that runs before `init()` method is invoked e.g. JVM initialization or Spring bean constructions. If anything it would be be more prudent to do it in the `main()` method but the fool proof way is to use `-D` options.

Answer (score 30):

You can configure the timezone with a class annotated with the `@Configuration` annotation. You can put it anywhere in your project. I typically house all classes that fit under this category in a package called `config`. Make sure you add the `@PostConstruct` annotation to the method that is actually setting the timezone.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
public class LocaleConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        System.out.println("Date in UTC: " + new Date().toString());
    }
}
```

See the [original article](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-application-set-default-timezone/)

Answer (score 6):

Post constructs don't work sometimes making it pre construct worked for me

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.app" })
public class Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Setting the timezone"+TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+9:00").getID());
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+9:00"));
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Did post construct not work at all or only for reading timezone before boot is completed?

Comment: PostConstruct did not work for me and I had to place it main and it works.

Answer (score 4):

More options in case your application is running under linux:

### Set `TZ` environment variable

See "In POSIX systems, a user can specify the time zone by means of the TZ environment variable" (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html).

This option is especially useful in any cloud environment.

### Symlink `/etc/locatime`

I.e. in my local system `/etc/locatime` symlinks to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin`:

```
➜ ls -l /etc/localtime  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 22. Jan 23:01 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin
```

You can easily change the symbolic link with `ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT /etc/localtime`, the possible values can be found within `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`.

This option can also be used in many cloud environments by mounting a hostvolume, see [kubernetes timezone in POD with command and argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089265/kubernetes-timezone-in-pod-with-command-and-argument).

Answer (score 1):

this worked like a charm for me on intellij when i run unit test :
you have to add  the command bellow on vm arguments GMT of junit or maven config (i don't know why UTC doesn't work for me ,hope this help u ^^  )

```
    -Duser.timezone="GMT+2"
```

Answer (score 0):

`<properties> <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=UTC</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments> </properties>` 
That did not work for me.

But if you use **jvmArguments** instead that worked for me.
Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/…

simply   `<configuration> <jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=UTC</jvmArguments> </configuration>`

Answer (score 0):

**-Duser.timezone=UTC** in Edit Configurations --> Modify Options --> Add VM Options so work with me

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you could also use BeanFactoryPostProcessor. BeanFactoryPostProcessors designed to modify bean definitions and are executed before beans initialization, so you have a chance to create all beans with required time zone. May be it does not cover all the cases, however, in some cases might be quite useful, for example, for applications where you should use default(server) time zone, however need to have the specific value for your tests.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

@Component
class TimeZoneLocaleBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, EnvironmentAware, Ordered {
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory ignored) throws BeansException {
        TimeZone.setDefault(
                TimeZone.getTimeZone(env.getProperty("server.time-zone", "UTC"))
        );
        Locale.setDefault(
                Locale.forLanguageTag(env.getProperty("server.locale", "en-US"))
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(final Environment environment) {
        this.env = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

And application-test.properties

```
server.locale=en-US
server.time-zone=UTC
```