# kubernetes timezone in POD with command and argument

Tags: kubernetes, timezone, command, yaml

I want to change timezone with command.
I know applying `hostpath`.

Could you know how to apply command ?

```
ln -snf /user/share/zoneinfor/$TZ /etc/localtime
```

it works well within container. But I don't know applying with command and arguments in yaml file.

Answer (score 33):

Setting TZ environment variable as below works fine for me on GCP Kubernetes.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: demo
        image: gcr.io/project/image:master
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
            - name: TZ
              value: Europe/Warsaw
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
```

Comment: So the environment variable TZ : Europe/Warsaw worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. It also works for me on Huawei Cloud Kubernetes

Comment: It did not work for me on Amzon EKS. Volume mounting answer above worked for me.

Comment: So to make the environment variable work for me I had to install `tzdata` package since it was not installed in my case. Following questions was helpful

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70968816/kubernetes-set-timezone-to-a-deployment?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 30):

You can change the `timezone` of your pod by using specific timezone config and hostPath volume to set specific timezone. Your yaml file will look something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox-sleep
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    args:
    - sleep
    - "1000000"
    volumeMounts:
    - name: tz-config
      mountPath: /etc/localtime
  volumes:
    - name: tz-config
      hostPath:
        path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Prague
        type: File
```

If you want it across all pods or deployments, you need to add volume and volumeMounts to all your deployment file and change the `path` value in `hostPath` section to the timezone you want to set.

Comment: I'm not getting this to work on Kubernetes v1.10.11. 
`container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/etc/localtime\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/[id]/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/[id]/merged/etc/localtime\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type`

Comment: I have got this to work on Kubernetes v1.17.4 and minikube v1.8.2. Just need to add the type: File in volumes config.

Answer (score 11):

In a deployment, you can do it by creating a volumeMounts in /etc/localtime and setting its values. Here is an example I have for a mariadb:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mariadb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mariadb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mariadb
          image: mariadb
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mariadb
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: password
          volumeMounts:
          - name: tz-config
            mountPath: /etc/localtime
      volumes:
      - name: tz-config
        hostPath:
           path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Madrid
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to add "hostPath" in the deployment config, as suggested in previous answers, you'll need to be a privileged user. Otherwise your deployment may fail on:

> "hostPath": hostPath volumes are not allowed to be used

As a workaround you can try one of theses options:

1. Add `allowedHostPaths: {}` next to volumes.
2. Add *TZ* environment variable. For example: `TZ = Asia/Jerusalem`

(Option 2 is similar to running `docker exec -it openshift/origin /bin/bash -c "export TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' && /bin/bash"`).

Comment: Thanks @StuartCharlton, I've updated solution (not only for Openshift)

Comment: Option2 is the best approach, for security reasons hostPath is not allowed in most of the managed kubernetes platforms.

Comment: I had been aimlessly trying to export external command and args through K8S manifest. All it took to make it work was using Noam's 2nd approach. Worked on a self managed cluster on AWS. Thanks @warden for present a nice YAML too.

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest way was to follow this article and write to to the Dockerfile:

https://dev.to/0xbf/set-timezone-in-your-docker-image-d22

#### TL;DR

```
RUN apt update && apt install tzdata -y
ENV TZ="America/New_York"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me: Setting up of volumes and volumeMounts didn't help. Setting up of TZ environment alone works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Setting TZ in kubernetes deployment.yaml should fix this issue

```
      env:
        - name: TZ
          value: Europe/Oslo
```