# Time Zone in Kubernetes Pods Using Environment Variable

Tags: kubernetes, timezone, mongodb-biconnector

I am trying to update my pod time to Asia/Kolkata zone as per [kubernetes timezone in POD with command and argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089265/kubernetes-timezone-in-pod-with-command-and-argument). However, the time still remains the same UTC time. Only the time zone is getting updated from UTC to Asia.

I was able to fix it using the volume mounts as below. Create a config map and apply the deployment yaml.

```
kubectl create configmap tz --from-file=/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata -n <required namespace>
```

**Why is the environmental variable method not working?  Will a pod eviction occur from one host to another if we use volume mount time and will if affect the volume mount time after pod eviction?**

The EV deployment YAML is below which does not update the time

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: connector
  labels:
    app: connector
  namespace: clients
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: connector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: connector
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: connector
        name: connector
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "32Mi"  # "64M"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "64Mi"  # "128M"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3307
            protocol: TCP
        env:
          - name: TZ
            value: Asia/Kolkata
        volumeMounts:
          - name: connector-rd
            mountPath: /home/mongobi/mongosqld.conf
            subPath: mongosqld.conf
      volumes:
      - name: connector-rd
        configMap:
          name: connector-rd
          items:
          - key: mongod.conf
```

Volume Mount yaml is below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: connector
  labels:
    app: connector
  namespace: clients
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: connector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: connector
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: connector
        name: connector
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "32Mi"  # "64M"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "64Mi"  # "128M"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3307
            protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
          - name: tz-config
            mountPath: /etc/localtime
          - name: connector-rd
            mountPath: /home/mongobi/mongosqld.conf
            subPath: mongosqld.conf
      volumes:
      - name: connector-rd
        configMap:
          name: connector-rd
          items:
          - key: mongod.conf
            path: mongosqld.conf
      - name: tz-config
        hostPath:
           path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: it happens only with kolkata? as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62641595/9929015), Europe/Warsaw works fine with the same example

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you need to mention type attribute as File for hostPath in the deployment configuration. The below configuration should work for you.

```
 - name: tz-config
        hostPath:
           path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata
           type: File
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting TZ env variable in deployment works for me