# How to change timezone at the server level in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Can we change the timezone at the server level. Suppose I want to deploy yugabytedb cluster by helm chart, then how can I set the default timezone for the cluster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such override right now. You may be able to achieve this by modifying the helm charts to add this TZ environment variable to the pod:

1. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-you-change-timezone-pods
2. [kubernetes timezone in POD with command and argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089265/kubernetes-timezone-in-pod-with-command-and-argument)