# Spring boot application with different date

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm

Is there a way to change the date of my application without changing the operating system?
I want to change to a specific date and not adjust the timezone.
I can not change the content of the application, it runs using spring boot.

For example, I would like to start my application with 07/12/2018, as if it were the date of my operating system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force a Spring Boot JVM into UTC time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316667/how-do-i-force-a-spring-boot-jvm-into-utc-time-zone)

Comment: As @vahdet mentioned, you could change the jvm settings, or docker could be another option.

Comment: @vahdet, it's not the same.
I want to change the date, not time zone.

Comment: Do you want this behavior for the whole application? Or only for testing?

Comment: For the application