# Intellij Timezone does not correspond to my machine/country time

Tags: intellij-idea

My Intellij timezone is not the same as my machine/country time, When I try to run my spring-boot application the run-console shows less hour than my machine time, and another problem is that when I try to persist to MySQL, the field which has java.util.Date saves time shown in  intellij not my local machine.

`2022-03-19 23:53:35.636`  INFO 14604 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888

where it should be GMT+01:00 :

`2022-03-19 00:53:35.636`  INFO 14604 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888

Comment: Try to set timezone as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54320993/8203759

Comment: Didn't work even date in mysql same as intellij (UTC) where it sould be (UTC+1)

Comment: Is it possible to share a sample project?

Comment: I just setted connection string to europe/amesterdam timezone and that worked ?`useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Amsterdam&useSSL=false` thank you Annikov.